# W7 gadget - js innerHTML don't work

Tags: javascript, html, windows-desktop-gadgets

I want to make a gadget that loads another page in an interval.

In IE 10 everything is working well, but as a gadget it does not work. Does anyone know where the problem is coming from?

```
<div class="obsah" id="obsah">
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' >
setInterval(obsah.innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="obsah.html"></object>', 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Could you briefly explain what you mean with "it does not work"?

Comment: Nothing is displayed in div "obsah". When i open page in IE 10, then "obsah" is filled with the contents of page obsah.html.

Comment: Try to replace `obsah.InnerHTML` with `document.getElementById("obsah").InnerHTML`. Is `<object>` a valid tag for desktop gadgets?

Comment: I tried it before, but it also does not work. I dont know if <object> is a valid tag for desktop gadgets and I do not know where to find out, is somewhere some documentation about gadgets?